# Need Duplicate Entries for Each Day For a Date Range in MS SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

*********Scenario**************

I have Bus Operation where some buses fill the fuel more than once in a day, let's say a bus (4345) filled the Fuel on 04/09/2017 one time and on 03/09/2017 fill the fuel 2 times.

I have query which run from a certain date (DateFrom and DateTo) and get the fuel entries for each vehicle which are more than one for this selected date range.........but what i need 
Results From Certain Date Range (DateFrom -- DateTo) and under this caretaria for each date for each vehicle how many times vehicle fill the fuel..for better understand you can see the image attached with this....
My Query which i am using is following:

```
WITH Records_counts AS 
    (
        SELECT f.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY bus1) ct
        FROM  Fuel.vFuelEntriesDetails f                
  )
    SELECT * FROM Records_counts WHERE  ct > 1  
    AND FuelEntryDate >='2017-09-03' and FuelEntryDate <'2017-09-05' 
        AND  ( BusNo BETWEEN '10161/1' AND  '10180/1' ) 
ORDER BY BusNo DESC
```

[image]

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results *as text* in your question.

Answer (score 2):

As @Gordon Linoff said,Please provide the sample data for clear understanding with expected output.

I have created following table for sample demo with my understanding:

Table:

```
create table tbl_vehicle
(
   busno varchar(10),
   plateno int,
   coldate date
);
```

Records:

```
insert into tbl_vehicle values('1016/1',4345,'2017-09-03'),('1016/1',4345,'2017-09-03'),
('1016/1',4345,'2017-09-03'),('1016/1',4345,'2017-09-04');
```

Query:

```
SELECT plateno,coldate,COUNT(*) as fuel_fill_count 
FROM tbl_vehicle
WHERE coldate BETWEEN '2017-09-03' and '2017-09-05' 
      and busno BETWEEN '1016/1' AND  '10180/1'
GROUP BY plateno,coldate
```

Output:

```
plateno coldate     fuel_fill_count
------------------------------------
4345    2017-09-03  3
4345    2017-09-04  1
```

Note: Tested on SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
;WITH Records_counts AS 
(
    SELECT f.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY FuelEntryDate, BusNo) ct
    FROM  Fuel.vFuelEntriesDetails f
)
SELECT * FROM Records_counts WHERE  
    FuelEntryDate >='2017-09-03' and FuelEntryDate <'2017-09-05' 
        AND  ( BusNo BETWEEN '10161/1' AND  '10180/1' ) 
ORDER BY BusNo DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

@sarslan....I am sorry, the results are wrong under this query....which you posted.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a cte for this, just add the date to your partition
As your FuelEntryDate is a datetime, you need to use only the date part

```
SELECT DATE(FuelEntryDate) EntryDate, f.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Busno, Date(FuelEntryDate)) ct
FROM  Fuel.vFuelEntriesDetails f
WHERE  
    FuelEntryDate BETWEEN '2017-09-03' AND FuelEntryDate '2017-09-05' 
    AND  ( BusNo BETWEEN '10161/1' AND  '10180/1' ) 
ORDER BY BusNo, FuelEntryDate
```

Answer (score 0):

@Gordon Linoff........... please check the image with these comments and table structure image above comments which i posted also read the comments on each image...

[image]